# Facebook error (#100) Could not resolve object at URL" when creating a user owned object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the Graph api on Facebook SDK for Unity (package 6.2.2) to create an object for each user to hold data on the levels they have completed. 
Using the code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dataD = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataD.Add("title", "Level Score");

Dictionary<string, object> dataS = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dataS.Add("score", score.ToString());
dataS.Add("userid", FB.UserId);

dataD.Add("data", dataS);

Dictionary<string, string> objectData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
objectData.Add("object", Json.Serialize(dataD));

FB.API("me/objects/<namespace>:<objectname>", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, CreateObjectCallback, objectData);
```

About 90% of the time the code, replacing the *namespace* and *objectname* with the correct names, to create an object works, the app receives a successfull callback and the object is created. The times when it fails the error message in the log reads as:

```
E/Unity   (19602): You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
E/Unity   (19602): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/<namespace>:<objectname>
E/Unity   (19602):
E/Unity   (19602): (Filename:  Line: 253)
```

After getting this problem to occur fairly consistantly I attempted to see if I could get any more information by using Facebook's Graph API Explorer and maybe determine if the problem is something in my code but I get the same problem there as well at about the same rate. When it fails in the explorer I can normally send the exact same data straight after the error and it will succeed.

The error code when it decides to fail in the Graph API Explorer is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Could not resolve object at URL 836692929751565.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I'm assuming this message means that Facebook has failed to create the object and so is giving me the error that it can't return the object it tried to create but I have been unable to find any information online pertaining to this kind of error.

Is there something I'm missing in the data I'm sending that could cause this or in this situation should I just catch this error and retry creating the object?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you ever found out where it was coming from?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did try getting putting it through Facebook's bug reporting system but despite being able to trigger this error at least once in every 10 objects that I tried to create myself on their Graph API Explorer, the tech support member was not able to so they closed it as not a bug.

Comment: Till we find a fix, I'll just be sending the object again if the API returns an error. Seems to be working but it's a hacky workaround.

Answer (score -1):

From what I could find on the subject it looks like you have some missing registry items. Error 100 is a general error that could mean:

```
• Access Denied Error 100
• Error 100 Access Denied Windstream
• Yahoo SiteBuilder Error 100
• Error 100 Time Warner Cable
• Microsoft Silverlight Error Code 100
```

How to fix a numeric error, you have to first know what the numeric code means. Each numeric code will have its own solution that can be done manually or you can use a product that will fix it automatically. To find out what the error code that you are seeing means, you can either refer to your computer’s manual or you can look up the number online and see what the results are.

Some of the more common fixes for a numeric error include:

```
•Making certain all programs on the computer are updated.
•Making certain that the Windows operating system being used is updated.
•Uninstalling and then reinstalling your Windows operating system.
 While these fixes may or may not work for your particular numeric error, they are a start.
```

http://www.erroranswers.com/troubleshooting/NM_100.php

I hope this helps....

Comment: This answer does not help at all I'm afraid as the problem I described is with the Facebook API not the Windows registry or a generic error code (see the java.io exception that is returned on an android device). I have been able to replicate this bug on several android and iOS devices as well as Facebook's own Graph API Explorer so I'm pretty sure there is more to it.